# Munin does not connect to SNMP service on Windows 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, snmp, munin

I'm using this tutorial to configure SNMP on my Windows server and Munin on my Linux server: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/Using_SNMP_plugins.
SNMP on the Windows server works fine, I have checked that with the snmpwalk tool on Linux.

When Munin runs an update I got the following error:

```
2011/10/03 15:20:22 Failed to connect to node 192.168.2.8:4949/tcp : Connection timed out
```

This is 'correct' since SNMP is UDP and runs on port 161. Did I miss something in the tutorial? I have the feeling the SNMP configurator of Munin is not setting the host to SNMP or something...

Comment: Munin is attempting to contact a munin-node.  You haven't configured it correctly.  What's your munin.conf, and how is your node setup so far?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have already fixed this issue. Something was wrong in my configuration indeed.